# powerpoint / openoffice plugin for syntax highlighting

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, powerpoint

I need to create a powerpoint which uses python code, and in the future potentially C++ code. I was wondering whether anyone knew a plugin which allows for a block of code (I know that you can use this http://www.fauskes.net/nb/syntaxms/ to allow to do a paste special, but I was hoping that I could just copy text from any text editor (I use a lot of different editors) and just paste it straight in there)

Comment: ...or you could just format the code with a monospace font instead., or take a screenshot from the IDE..I'm not entirely sure what your question is.

Comment: My question was is there a powerpoint plugin for syntax highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just suggest you to use the following tool chain:

1. Use reST and/or Sphinix to write whatever code, python, C++, ...
2. use rst2odt.py or Sphinix tool to convert it to .odt file (open document text, opensource)
3. Save it to MS .doc file
4. copy to Powerpoint from Word